# Delphi IDE and UNC

Tags: delphi, ide, unc

I use Delphi 10.3.3.

When I open a project from local drive:

`c:\projects-2010\neswin\fiat\nesfiat.dproj`

Some of the source files open with a UNC full path, eg:

`\\roni10-pc\roni10-pc\projects-2010\neswin\fiat\mainmenu.pas`

[image]

When I close it, and re-open `mainmenu.pas` from the IDE (file/open), it shows OK (no UNC):

`c:\projects-2010\neswin\fiat\mainmenu.pas`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the `.dproj` file with a text editor to see if it contains actual UNC paths in it?

Comment: The network share is `roni10-c`, not `roni10-pc` - check your own screenshot. Only your computer name is `roni10-pc`.

Comment: Delete Projectname.dsk if it is there

Comment: Thanks, the dsk file contains the this line :CurrentEditView=\\roni10-pc\roni10-c\Projects-2010\neswin\CardCli.pas